# Errors with non-mapped child entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a `Parent` and `Child` class/table and I'm using Fluent API to configure my mapping.  The tables are joined on non primary key fields in each table, so according to what I've read, I can't configure the join in Entity Framework.  Because of that, I'm going to load my `Parent.Children` property manually (`parent.Children = (from x in context.Children...`)

However, I'm getting an exception on my mapping of `Parent`.  My classes look like

```
public class Parent
{
   // Unique primary key
   public int ParentPrimaryKey { get; set; }

   // These two fields together compose the foreign key to join to Child
   public string ParentForeignKey1 { get; set; }
   public string ParentForeignKey2 { get; set; }

   public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
   // Unique primary key
   public int ChildPrimaryKey { get; set; }

   // These two fields together compose the (non-unique) foreign key to join to Parent
   public string ChildForeignKey1 { get; set; }
   public string ChildForeignKey2 { get; set; }

}
```

When I try to query `context.Parents`, I get an exception because the SQL that Entity Framework generates is trying to join `Parent` to `Child` and is looking for a property on `Child` called `Child_ParentPrimaryKey`.

If I add `modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().Ignore(p => p.Children);` I get the exception `System.NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'Packages' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.`

How can I keep `Children` as a non-mapped property on `Parent` without getting errors?

Comment: `Ignore` should work in this case. I believe the mapping is alright and the error is in the query. `NotSupportedException` sounds like you are using the unmapped collection navigation property `Packages` in your query and in a way that is not supported. Can you show the complete query you are using?

Comment: Thank you so much @V.Leon!  This problem was driving me crazy, and your comment pointed out the problem.  I was using the `Children` navigation property in my query.  I removed that, and it's working now.

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude a property from EF mapping by adding the `[NotMapped]` attribute:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
public class Parent {
   // ...

   [NotMapped]
   public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

[DataAnnotations - NotMapped Attribute](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/notmapped-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Isn't `Ignore` supposed to do the same thing?  I'm trying to separate my models into their own project, and not have it dependent on Entity Framework.

Comment: Actually, `Ignore` should work too. Did you show the actual code that produces the error? Because the error message you are getting talks about a member "Packages" that is not supported. Do you have a special getter on `Packages` or other custom C# that might prevent EF from mapping?

Comment: Sorry, the `Packages` property in the actual code corresponds to the `Children` property in this code.  In the actual code, `Packages` is `public List<Order> Packages { get; set; }` and `Order` corresponds to `Parent` here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who responded.  Your comments made me realize the problem was that I was using the `Parent.Children` property in my LINQ query.  I removed that, and it's working now.